# Retrieve Function names in file using vbscript

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to retrieve all function names in text file using VBScript but no luck so far.

```
Function getProductName()
```

For that I have used regular expression as below to get substring but it is not working.

```
"^Function([.*]?)\("
```

Comment: Remove square brackets.

Comment: also with `^` it will detect them only at exact beginning of string, or beginning of lines if multiline (no spaces or such allowed before them or else they won't be detected)

Answer (score 0):

You want

- the `Function` keyword (`\bFunction`)
- mandatory whitespace (`\s+`)
- in group 1 the function name (`\w+` is close enough)
- optional whitespace (`\s*`)
- an opening parenthesis (`\(`

Although the last two things are not strictly necessary for the task.

So this would work:

```
\bFunction\s+(\w+)\s*\(
```

And this would work as well:

```
\bFunction\s+(\w+)
```

Use with the Global flag set to `True`.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. It worked very well. Appreciate your quick response.